# Redis mock in nodejs cannot stub non-existent property createClient

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, redis, sinon

I have a problem trying to mock the redis `createClient()` method in NodeJS using mocha and sinon. This is a snippet of my index.js. Inside the socket class, there is a create redis connection. Now in my unit test, i encountered this error `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property createClient`. I can't seem to figure out why? Is it due to some ordering of the mocking?

```js
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http');
const redis = require('redis');
const expressApp = express();
const server = http.createServer(expressApp);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    pingInterval: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 5000
});
const config = require('config');
const log = require('gelf-pro');
const HTTP_PORT = 3000;

// Socket IO call backs
io.on("connection", (client) => {    
    new Socket(client);
});

// export the server so it can be easily called for testing
exports.server = server.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    log.info('socketio server started at port ' + HTTP_PORT);
});
```

Unit test code:

```js
'use strict'

var expect = require('chai').expect
  , redis = require('redis')
  , redisMock = require('redis-mock')
  , sinon = require('sinon')
  , io = require('socket.io-client')
  , ioOptions = { 
      transports: ['websocket']
    , forceNew: true
    , reconnection: false
  }
  , testMsg = JSON.stringify({message: 'HelloWorld'})
  , sender
  , receiver
  



describe('Chat Events', function(){
  beforeEach(function(done){

    sinon
      .stub(redis.RedisClient.prototype, 'createClient')
      .callsFake(function() {
        console.log('mock redis called');
        return redisMock.createClient();
      });
    
    // connect two io clients
    sender = io('http://localhost:3000/', ioOptions)
    receiver = io('http://localhost:3000/', ioOptions)
    
    // finish beforeEach setup
    done()
  })
  afterEach(function(done){
    
    // disconnect io clients after each test
    sender.disconnect()
    receiver.disconnect()
    done()
  })

  describe('Message Events', function(){
    it('Clients should receive a message when the `message` event is emited.', function(done){
      sender.emit('message', testMsg)
      receiver.on('ackmessage', function(msg){
        expect(msg).to.contains(testMsg)
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redis.createClient` method is a standalone function, **NOT** a method of a prototype. If you use TypeScript, we can check the types of `redis` package.

`index.d.ts`:

```js
export function createClient(port: number, host?: string, options?: ClientOpts): RedisClient;
export function createClient(unix_socket: string, options?: ClientOpts): RedisClient;
export function createClient(redis_url: string, options?: ClientOpts): RedisClient;
export function createClient(options?: ClientOpts): RedisClient;
```

So, you should stub it like this:

`index.js`:

```js
const redis = require('redis');

function main() {
  redis.createClient();
}

module.exports = main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const main = require('./');
const redis = require('redis');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('62909606', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const createClientStub = sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').callsFake(function() {
      console.log('mock redis called');
    });
    main();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(createClientStub);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  62909606
mock redis called
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (9ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```